# Yii : Is it possible to know which configuration file Yii::app() is using

Tags: php, yii

I am having problem with Yii::app()

in protected/config/main.php

```
'params' => require(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../mainsite_config.php'),
```

in mainsite_config.php

```
<?php return array("siteurl"=> "http://domainname.com" ,"recaptch_key"=>"public key" ,'recaptcha_private_key'=>'private key')
```

but code  Yii::app()->params['recaptcha_key'] returns empty value.

So I want to know which configuration file Yii:app() is currently using. Please help me

Answer (score 1):

I think you can solve this with pure php :D

make another property in the returning array like

```
 [
   'dir' => __FILE__,
   ...
```

and will get your file name in `params`